# How do I change the background colour in a Word 2010 style?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I have a header style with a navy blue background (`TH1` in the screen shot below). How do I change the background colour?

[image]

I can see the colour defined in the markup as a pattern:

```
Font: Verdana, 14 pt, Not Bold, Font color: White, Space
    Before:  6 pt
    After:  6 pt
    Pattern: Clear (Custom Color(RGB(10,81,161)))
    Based on: Heading 1
```

But I'm at a loss as to where that's configured.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To change the background (shading):

- **Click** the `Format` button in the bottom-left
- **Click** `Border...`

  [image: format > border]
- Go to the `Shading` tab.

  [image: shading]

Comment: My word-fu failed me completely today +1

Comment: still does the job in Word 2016!

Comment: Sneaky of them to hide this under "Borders".

Answer (score 2):

First insert a table, even a 1 by 1 table will do. Now type a word inside the table. Highlight this word and right-click on it, you will notice that the tools that now pop up include a shading tool. Shade this word as wanted, any background color you select. Now copy this word to your regular text area of your word document & give it the correct size, font, etc wanted. Now you can remove the table.

For some reason the tools that come up when right-clicking on highlighted text inside a table are different than the tools for standard text in a document.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the trick is to change the background fill on an existing style in the document itself then right click and select:

```
Styles -> Update <style_name> to Match Selection
```